# Can't Start Weblogic Admin Server as Service - Cause Can't connect to Host

Tags: oracle, windows-services, localhost, weblogic, weblogic12c

I set up a weblogic service Admin Server in my local laptop. We use it to give demos. So I need the service to be started so it's easy when other people use the service as well.

I installed Weblogic as a service with the following install script and it installs successfully.

```
SETLOCAL
set DOMAIN_NAME=MyDomain
set USERDOMAIN_HOME=C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\<MyDomain>
set SERVER_NAME=AdminServer

set MEM_ARGS=-Xms512m -Xmx2048m
set WL_HOME=C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver

set HOST=127.0.0.1
set PORT=7001

set WLS_USER=weblogic
set WLS_PW=oracle123

set PRODUCTION_MODE=false

set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dweblogic.Stdout="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\<myDomain>\log\stdout.txt" -Dweblogic.Stderr="C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\<myDomain>\log\stderr.txt" %JAVA_OPTIONS%
call "C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\wlserver\server\bin\installSvc.cmd"

ENDLOCAL
```

When I try to start the service, I get the following stdout logs when I run

```
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [initLog] initializing logger
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [E] [initLog] No 'ROTATION_TYPE' header found. 'TIME' based rotation will be used by default.
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [E] [initLog] No 'TIME_START_DATE' header found or value is invalid. Rotation will take place every 24 hours beginning today at 23:59:59
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [E] [initLog] No 'TIME_INTERVAL_MINS' header found. Using the default value of 24 hours.
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [E] [initLog] No 'MAX_FILE_COUNT' header found. Using the default of '-1' or no limit.
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [initLog] TIME based log rotation is ON
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [trigger] First rotation due in 44267 secs
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] console allocation successful. THREAD_DUMP redirection enabled
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] About to execute CreateThread()
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszCmdLine = -server -Xms32m -Xmx200m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dweblogic.Stdout=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\MyDomain\log\stdout.txt -Dweblogic.Stderr=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\MyDomain\log\stderr.txt  -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_8\jre\lib\endorsed;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\endorsed -classpath "C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_8\lib\tools.jar;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\oracle_common\modules\net.sf.antcontrib_1.1.0.0_1-0b3\lib\ant-contrib.jar;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\modules\features\oracle.wls.common.nodemanager_2.0.0.0.jar;" -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Dweblogic.management.username=weblogic -Dweblogic.ProductionModeEnabled= -Djava.security.policy="C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\lib\weblogic.policy" weblogic.Server
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszJavaHome = C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_8
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszExecDir = C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\MyDomain
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszOldPath = C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\mule\mule-enterprise-3.5.1\bin;C:\ActiveMQ\bin;
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszNewPath = C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_8\jre\bin;C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK17~1.0_8\bin;C:\app\oracle\MIDDLE~1\ORACLE~1\wlserver\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8;C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_2\bin;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\cygwin64\bin;C:\mule\mule-enterprise-3.5.1\bin;C:\ActiveMQ\bin;
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszDelay = 0
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszStopClass = []
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszLog = [C:\app\oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\MyDomain\log\stdout.txt]
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] Thread created successfully
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] Reporting SCM of SERVICE_START_PENDING with delay=0
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszHost = [127.0.0.1]
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] lpszPort = [7001]
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] pinging the host with max retry limit of 5
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] trying to open a connection to host
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [StartJVM] Parsing JVM Arguments
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [StartJVM] Initializing JVM
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] connection attempt failed. retrying
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [RunJavaApp] Loading class - weblogic.Server
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [RunJavaApp] Locating method "public static void main([]String)" in main class
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [RunJavaApp] Building arguments for main class
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:12 2015] [I] [RunJavaApp] Invoking main class
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:12 AM EST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090905> <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.> 
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:12 AM EST> <Info> <Security> <BEA-090906> <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to FIPS186PRNG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.> 
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:13 AM EST> <Info> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000377> <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 24.80-b11 from Oracle Corporation.> 
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:13 AM EST> <Info> <Management> <BEA-141107> <Version: WebLogic Server 12.1.3.0.0  Wed May 21 18:53:34 PDT 2014 1604337 > 
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:14 AM EST> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:14 AM EST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002900> <Initializing self-tuning thread pool.> 
<Nov 2, 2015 11:42:14 AM EST> <Info> <WorkManager> <BEA-002942> <CMM memory level becomes 0. Setting standby thread pool size to 256.> 
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:17 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] trying to open a connection to host
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:18 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] connection attempt failed. retrying
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:23 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] trying to open a connection to host
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:24 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] connection attempt failed. retrying
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:29 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] trying to open a connection to host
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:30 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] connection attempt failed. retrying
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:35 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] trying to open a connection to host
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:36 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] connection attempt failed. retrying
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:41 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] Reporting SCM of SERVICE_RUNNING
[Mon Nov 02 11:42:41 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] waiting for multiple events
[Mon Nov 02 11:43:34 2015] [I] [ServiceStop] invoked with stopclass=
[Mon Nov 02 11:43:34 2015] [I] [ServiceStop] Informing SCM about SERVICE_STOP_PENDING
[Mon Nov 02 11:43:34 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] done waiting for multiple events. Wait=0
[Mon Nov 02 11:43:34 2015] [I] [ServiceStart] Informing SCM about SERVICE_STOP
```

Any help as to why the service isn't able to connect to localhost would be appreciated.

I tried installing as HOST=127.0.0.1 and HOST=localhost to no avail. I also included the line 
127.0.0.1 localhost
to my /Windows/System32/drivers/etc/hosts file and still i am unable to connect with the service.

Am I setting the service up wrong somehow?

Comment: Did you try replacing it with the actual hostname ?

Comment: no i have not tried that. Would the host name be Computer name?

Comment: Yes. On the windows command line type "hostname".

Comment: @user I can't believe that's what it took. Machine name instead of IP THANK YOU SO MUCH!